# Index.php ? in url after 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have moved all the content from old site to new site, now I want to 301 redirect all pages from old site to new site, with same URL.

Example:

- `http://www.oldsite.net/en/newspage.html`  to `http://www.newsite.com/en/newspage.html`
- `http://www.oldsite.net/en/aboutus.html`  to `http://www.newsite.com/en/about.html`

Thsi is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddoamin\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And this redirects all the pages on same page on new site,

But new site has `index.php?` in URL after redirecting. For example:

```
http://www.newsite.com/index.php?/en/about.html
```

Sites are developed in codeigniter.

Anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: What is your `$config['index_page']` value?

Comment: $config['index_page'] = ' ';

Comment: Just move your last 2 lines of `.htaccess` to top or just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Thank you anubhava, but it's not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @anubhava mentioned in comments, your directives are in the wrong order. Your redirect needs to go *before* the front controller. (As a general rule, *external redirects* should always go before *internal rewrites*.) For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddoamin\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However, you will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as the earlier (erroneous) 301 redirect will have gotten cached hard by the browser.

If you have the redirect *after* the front controller then the request is first rewritten to `/index.php?/en/about.html` and then redirected. Hence why the redirect is messed up.